# Handling ArrayBuffer in mqtt message callback

Tags: node.js, binary, mqtt, payload

A mqtt client send a binary message to certain topic. My node.js client subscribes to the topic and recieves the binary data. As our architecture payload is Int16Array. But I cannot cast it successfully to Javascript array.
//uint16 array `[255, 256, 257, 258]` sent as message payload, which contents  `<ff 00 00 01 01 01 02 01>`

When I do this:

```js
 mqttClient.on("message", (topic, payload) => {
      console.log(payload.buffer);
   })
```

The output like:

```
ArrayBuffer {
  [Uint8Contents]: <30 11 00 07 74 65 73 74 6f 7a 69 ff 00 00 01 01 01 02 01>,
  byteLength: 19
}
```

which cant be cast to Int16Array because of odd length
It also contains more bytes than the original message

Answer (score 1):

As it seems the original bytes exist at the end of the payload, which is offset for some reason.

Buffer also contains the offset and byte length information inside. By using them casting should be successful.

```
let arrayBuffer = payload.buffer.slice(payload.byteOffset,payload.byteOffset + payload.byteLength)
let int16Array = new Int16Array(arrayBuffer)
let array = Array.from(arrayBuffer)
```